# How to perform SOAP requests from React JS application?

Tags: reactjs, soap

Is there any way to use SOAP service and pass requests to it from React application? I tried both soap and easysoap for node.js but react immediatly throws an error when I try to use them.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: When I add:
var easysoap = require('easysoap'); 

My console outputs: 
TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function. (In 'fs.readFileSync(__dirname + path.sep + 'request.tpl', 'utf-8')', 'fs.readFileSync' is undefined)

Comment: Do you have a `var fs = require('fs');` line ?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you are trying to use easysoap from a React app directly.

Browser in which your app is being run doesn't have access to readFileSync function, and this is the reason you are getting the error.

You will need to implement alternatives such as:

- https://github.com/doedje/jquery.soap
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/tinysoap